# JQuery Draggable: "cancel" element nested within "handle" element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to make a `div` draggable, using an element nested within it as the handle. To accomplish this, I can use JQuery UI's [Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) with a `handle` option.

However, I would like to prevent dragging when an element nested within the *handle* element is dragged. Adding a `cancel` option doesn't seem to work.

Is this kind of behaviour possible using Draggable?

---

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M6qdh/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="titleBar">
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <div class="close">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".dialog").draggable({
    handle: $(".titleBar"),
    cancel: $(".close")
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to prevent the `mousedown` event from bubbling up the DOM tree from the close button:

```
$(".dialog").draggable({
    handle: $(".titleBar")
});

$(".close").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M6qdh/2/).